# I'm uploading images on S3 but not getting back imageLocation just getting ETag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer, aws-sdk-nodejs

**Image is uploaded on S3 server but in response just getting ETag not the imageLocation**

```
{
    "ETag": "\"917515db74ea8d1aee6a246cfbcc0b45\""
}
```

**Bucket Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Principal": {},
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [],
            "Resource": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your bucket policy is invalid and is also probably irrelevant for your question. The Amazon S3 object will be uploaded to the Key that you specified. Can you point us to any documentation that suggests you should receive back an object location?

Comment: [YT Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtuCCfren_I)
To save your time 29:00 - 31:00 he will get response with ETag as well as image location! @JohnRotenstein